# Jenkins console ignores newlines

Tags: python, jenkins, console, output, newline

Python script is triggered by a Jenkins build. The output generated by Python's `print()` is then transmitted to Jenkins.

Each Python's output string is postabmled by \r\n which, however, is misinterpreted while displaying text in Jenkins console output in browser.

The \r\n are then just displayed as plain text, not interpreted by Jenkins as a command to start a new line. I do not know how to make the \r\n symbols be interpreted as newline in Jenkins console.

How do I resolve this problem? Do I modify my Python `print()` or apply some additional settings in Jenkins?

Comment: did you end up solving this?

Comment: Unfortunately, not.